# Integral of double sin

Tags: definite-integrals

Consider $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $l\in\mathbb{N}$. How do I calculate the integral that follows?
$$\int_0^L x\sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi l x}{L}\right) dx$$

Comment: Try using the product-to-sum trig identity to turn that into a sum of sines

Comment: Acually, it is a subtraction of cosines.

Comment: $ 2\sin(A) \sin(B) = \cos(A-B) - \cos(A+B)$

Comment: $y=\frac{x\pi}{L}$ makes problem clearer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Note $\cos(ax \pm bx) = \cos ax \cos bx \mp \sin ax \sin bx$, so
$$\sin ax \sin bx = \tfrac12\cos(ax - bx)-\tfrac12\cos(ax+bx)$$

Note also that you can integrate by parts:
$$\int x\cos kx\; dx = \int x\;d(\tfrac1k\sin kx) = \tfrac1k x\sin kx - \int\tfrac1k \sin kx \; dx = \tfrac1k x\sin kx + \tfrac1{k^2}\cos kx$$

With these, you can perform the integration easily.